# Radial component of acceleration in simple pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

I have a slight issue with the simple pendulum problem. mathematically, the equations make complete sense, but, when i look at the problem in more intuitive manner, i get the following issue. in an infinitesimal displacement, dv vector is in the theta hat direction and acceleration must be completely in the theta direction. I mean it makes sense cause in the infinitesimal limit, the path looks like a straight line. the part that I don't get is, in reality, there is a radial acceleration too. my question is how is this possible?

Comment: Why do you think that acceleration must be in the direction of $\hat\theta$?

Comment: I mean, acceleration is defined to be the vector dv to dt. So dv and acceleration must be in the same direction, right

Comment: Not in this case of radial motion. The acceleration is always perpendicular to the velocity. Please look at _centripetal force_ in the context of a simple pendulum.

Comment: I think i had a wrong assumption. dv is not entirely in theta hat direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple words, *tangential acceleration* changes velocity vector amplitude (i.e. speed) and *radial acceleration* changes velocity vector direction.

Here is the detailed derivation for the two acceleration components in a pendulum: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/685423/149541

In circular motion, displacement and velocity vectors are perpendicular which is obvious since velocity is tangent on the path. Your intuition is correct when it comes to tangential acceleration - it points in the direction of the velocity vector. But this acceleration component alone cannot describe how velocity vector direction changes.